# "URLEncoder cannot be resolved" - URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(),"UTF-8");

Tags: android, eclipse, rest, http-post

I´ve seen similars code that use this but i gives me this error "URLEncoder cannot be resolved" on this line:

String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(),"UTF-8");

It says the function is encode(String s, String enc)
On "enc" it says the encoded scheme to be used.

I´m running Eclipse SDK Version: 3.6.1 and i don´t know how to solve this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you possibly missing an "import java.net.URLEncoder"?  Eclipse should recommend adding that if you click on the icon on the left side next to the line.